# Custom LLM from API for QA chain in Langchain

Tags: python, python-requests, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

Currently, I want to build RAG chatbot for production.
I already had my LLM API and I want to create a custom LLM and then use this in RetrievalQA.from_chain_type function.
I don't know whether Langchain support this in my case.

I read about this topic on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/LangChain/comments/17v1rhv/integrating_llm_rest_api_into_a_langchain/
And in langchain document: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/llms/custom_llm

But this still does not work when I apply the custom LLM to qa_chain.
Below is my code, hope for the support from you, sorry for my language, english is not my mother tongue.

```
from pydantic import Extra
import requests
from typing import Any, List, Mapping, Optional

from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManagerForLLMRun
from langchain.llms.base import LLM

class LlamaLLM(LLM):
    llm_url = 'https:/myhost/llama/api'

    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

    @property
    def _llm_type(self) -> str:
        return "Llama2 7B"

    def _call(
        self,
        prompt: str,
        stop: Optional[List[str]] = None,
        run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForLLMRun] = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> str:
        if stop is not None:
            raise ValueError("stop kwargs are not permitted.")

        payload = {
            "inputs": prompt,
            "parameters": {"max_new_tokens": 100},
            "token": "abcdfejkwehr"
        }

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

        response = requests.post(self.llm_url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # print("API Response:", response.json())

        return response.json()['generated_text']  # get the response from the API

    @property
    def _identifying_params(self) -> Mapping[str, Any]:
        """Get the identifying parameters."""
        return {"llmUrl": self.llm_url}
```

```
llm = LlamaLLM()
```

```
#Testing
prompt = "[INST] Question: Who is Albert Einstein? \n Answer: [/INST]"
result = llm._call(prompt)
print(result)

Albert Einstein (1879-1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who is widely regarded as one of the most influential scientists of the 20th century. He is best known for his theory of relativity, which revolutionized our understanding of space and time, and his famous equation E=mc².
```

```
# Build prompt
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
template = """[INST] <<SYS>>

Answer the question base on the context below.

<</SYS>>

Context: {context}
Question: {question}
Answer:
[/INST]"""
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context", "question"],template=template,)

# Run chain
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm,
                                       verbose=True,
                                       # retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(),
                                       retriever=custom_retriever,
                                       return_source_documents=True,
                                       chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT})
```

```
question = "Is probability a class topic?"
result = qa_chain({"query": question})
result["result"]

Encountered some errors. Please recheck your request!
```

The custom retrieval in my case combined retrieval and rerank. I already test and it's OK.

I also test with the normal retrieval, but it still don't work. So I think the retrieval is not the cause for the error.

```
retriever=vectordb.as_retriever()
```

Besides, it also has the issue related to insecure request, but whether it affect to the requests. (I also don't know how to fix it)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1061: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'myhost'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Encountered some errors. Please recheck your request!
```

Moreover, below is the api format which I have, does it have any problem?

```
curl --location 'https:/myhost:10001/llama/api' -k \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "inputs": "[INST] Question: Who is Albert Einstein? \n Answer: [/INST]",
    "parameters": {"max_new_tokens":100},
    "token": "abcdfejkwehr"
}
```

This happens because of the context length setting of the API. So I already fixed it and it's work fine.

Comment: I explained it here, if you could look into it would be great - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760091/llm-application-throwing-error-for-the-rag-approach?noredirect=1#comment137088227_77760091

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and meet no any problem. Maybe the custom_retriever failed. If you can provide more info about it?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and testing in my case. So this approach worked fine but maybe the different configs led to the issue.

The custom retrieval in my case combined retrieval and rerank. I already test and it's OK.

I also test with the normal retrieval, but it still don't work. So I think the retrieval is not the cause for the error.
`
retriever=vectordb.as_retriever()
`

Comment: I already updated some config regarding API, I would appreciate it if you take the time to support. Thank you.

Comment: This happen because the context length setting of the API. I already updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same example and getting another error. Please find the details below.

I have tried the RetrievalQA Chain as per the example. Only change is instead of PDF loader I have CSV file and I used CSV Loader; while calling the chain with question I am getting an error. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
question = "Is probability a class topic?"
result = qa_chain({"query": question}) ==> This line throws the below error
result["result"]
```

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 2
1 question = "Is probability a class topic?"
----> 2 result = qa_chain({"query": question })
3 print(result["result"])
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:312, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
310 except BaseException as e:
......
--> 808 if task in custom_tasks:
809 normalized_task = task
810 targeted_task, task_options = clean_custom_task(custom_tasks[task])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).