# LLM Application throwing Error for the RAG Approach

Tags: python, large-language-model

I was doing the example as per the explanation here - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/get-insight-from-your-business-data-build-llm-application-jain/

**I have tried the RetrievalQA Chain as per the example. Only change is instead of PDF loader I have CSV file and I used CSV Loader; while calling the chain with question I am getting an error. Please let me know how to resolve this.**

```
question = "Is probability a class topic?"
result = qa_chain({"query": question}) ==> This line throws the below error
result["result"]
```

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 2
1 question = "Is probability a class topic?"
----> 2 result = qa_chain({"query": question })
3 print(result["result"])
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:312, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
310 except BaseException as e:
.......
........
--> 808 if task in custom_tasks:
809 normalized_task = task
810 targeted_task, task_options = clean_custom_task(custom_tasks[task])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Please find complete code below:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import CSVLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM,pipeline
from langchain import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

file = '<<path to CSV File>>'
loader = CSVLoader(file_path=file, encoding='utf8')
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=150)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
modelPath = "<hugging face local folder>\all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device':'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings':False}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
  model_name = modelPath,
  model_kwargs = model_kwargs,
  encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)
db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("<<huggingface local folder>>\flan-t5-large")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("<<huggingface local folder>>\flan-t5-large")
pipe = pipeline("text2text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
llm = HuggingFacePipeline(
    pipeline = pipeline,
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "max_length": 512},
)
template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer. Keep the answer as concise as possible. 
{context}
Question: {question}
Helpful Answer:"""
QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(   
  llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
  chain_type="stuff",   
  retriever=db.as_retriever(),   
  chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": QA_CHAIN_PROMPT} 
) 
question = "Is probability a class topic?"
result = qa_chain({"query": question }) 
print(result["result"])
```

Comment: Can you show the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your error? Right now, you haven't shown us how you've defined `qa_chain`, and so there's not much to go on

Comment: code is exactly same as in the example link. Instead of PDF Loader I used CSV Loader as below:. All other steps are same. ``` loader = CSVLoader(file_path=file, encoding='utf8')
documents = loader.load() ```

Comment: @ C.Nivs - Can you please look into the complete program I have copied above.